# array_diff() leaving empty array keys

Tags: php, array-difference

Maybe I'm missing something here, but `array_diff()` seems to be leaving me empty kesys at the end of an array.

With this example data -

```
$term_ids = array(0 => 242, 1 => 270);
$term_ids = array_diff($term_ids, array(242, 243, 266, 267, 268, 269));
```

I am being left with this -

```
Array
(
    [1] => 270
    [0] => 
)
```

From what I understand, this is incorrect ([0] should be unset, leaving just [1]). I am using `$term_ids = array_values($term_ids);` after to make the keys correct, but it seems that this should not be necessary, so I'm wondering if someone who knows more than me could clarify?

Comment: First off, you have a typo up there ($term_id/s)

Comment: It works for me when the following corrections to the above are made: 1) `$terms_ids` requires the `array` keyword, such that `array(0=>` on line 1, and 2) `$term_id` needs to be `$term_ids` (plural) on the 2nd line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried

```
<?php

$arr1 = array(15, 16, 17,18);
$arr2 = array(15, 17);

$arr3 = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);

var_dump($arr3);
```

?>

and I got [1] => 16, [3] => 18.

This actually seems to be the intended result as the example on [the offical page](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) shows.

Answer (score 2):

Unable to reproduce:

```
$term_ids = array(0 => 242, 1 => 270);
$term_ids = array_diff($term_ids, array(242, 243, 266, 267, 268, 269));
print_r($term_ids);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 270
)
```